# Code signing a ClickOnce project from a hardware token

Tags: visual-studio, code-signing

I am using VS 2022 to publish a WPF application with ClickOnce. Currently, I sign the code during the publication process from a .pfx file. However, after June 1st, I will no longer be able to get the certificate/private key any other way than on a hardware token. And, I can't install the private key to the workstation from the token. The only other option for signing during the ClickOnce process is to use a certificate from the local certificate storage, but, as mentioned, this won't work because the hardware token will not allow the private key to be moved to a workstation.

So, what is the process of signing a ClickOnce project if you are using a code signing certificate located on a hardware token?

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to sign the manifest file using the hardware token?

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble with this and finally figured it out today.

When I would try to use the hardware key I would be prompted to enter the key and was prompted for a password by the signing software.  In my case Sectigo software.   I would enter the password and would be prompted again thinking that the password wasn't being accepted.  The publish would fail with an error about a file being inaccessible because it was open.

To keep this from being a super long post I found out that I had to enter the password several times and do it quickly so Visual Studio wouldn't give up and time out when waiting for the file signing process to be completed.

So, enter the password often and quickly and you should be ok.

Good luck!