# What is the most appropriate way to sign ClickOnce applications from June 1st onwards?

Tags: visual-studio, code-signing

I have been signing my ClickOnce application with a code signing certificate from the personal certificate store on my workstation (Windows) for some years now. Since June 1st 2023, that is not possible any more - certificate files cannot be purchased as before.
How should I sign my program from Visual Studio from now on? I have seen some instructions how to sign the code in some other ways, but I would like to keep it simple.
This is basically the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75768232/code-signing-a-clickonce-project-from-a-hardware-token) (which is still without an answer - @Intensivist, have you managed to resolve this?)